# jsp and css formatting

Tags: css, jsp

So basically i'm formatting a code, and the spacing isn't formatting for the id but the color is, why is it picking up on one of the formatting elements and not the others.

jsp code

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web_project1/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script> 
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="Stylesheet.css"/>
<title>Sam's Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="format" id="title">Sam's Game</h1>
<h1 id="you">You <span id="enemy">Opponent</span></h1>
<h1 id="stats">Stats:<span id="theirStats">Stats:</span></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And my css file

```css
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
#title {
font-family: Snap ITC, chiller;
font-size: 50px;
color:red;
text-align:center;
}
.format{
background-color:yellow;
margin-left: 480px;
width:360px;
height:60px; 
}
#you {
margin-left:150px;
font-family:verdana;
color:blue;
font-size:25px;

}
#enemy{
margin-left:850px;
font-family:verdana;
color:blue;
font-size:25px;

}
#stats{
margin-left: 90;
font-family: comic;
color:green;

}
#theirStats{
margin-left: 800;
font-family: comic;
color:green;

}
```

I'm probably missing something simple but anyways, the margin-left should add spacing to look like

```
Stats:                                               Stats:
```

but it's currently appearing

```
Stats:Stats:
```

^^ in green font currently

Comment: you forgot units: `margin-left: 800;`. 800 **WHAT**? pixels? inches? nanoparsecs?

Comment: thank you i feel humiliated

Comment: no worries. it's a very easy oversight, and it's friday...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `margin-left: 90px` and `margin-left: 800px` instead of `margin-left: 90` and `margin-left: 800`

Try this..

```css
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
#title {
font-family: Snap ITC, chiller;
font-size: 50px;
color:red;
text-align:center;
}
.format{
background-color:yellow;
margin-left: 480px;
width:360px;
height:60px; 
}
#you {
margin-left:150px;
font-family:verdana;
color:blue;
font-size:25px;

}
#enemy{
margin-left:850px;
font-family:verdana;
color:blue;
font-size:25px;

}
#stats{
margin-left: 90px;
font-family: comic;
color:green;

}
#theirStats{
margin-left: 800px;
font-family: comic;
color:green;

}
```

```html
<h1 class="format" id="title">Sam's Game</h1>
<h1 id="you">You <span id="enemy">Opponent</span></h1>
<h1 id="stats">Stats:<span id="theirStats">Stats:</span></h1>
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6o00zz7L/)